# What would you translate “puer rem graviter ferebat” to in English?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Please help with my Latin translation to english, I initially though it was the boy was carrying a heavy thing but I know “graviter” can have several meanings

Comment: More context might help. As you say *gravis* (or the **adverb**  *graviter*) might mean few things, but so is the case with *fero* which is very popular verb in Latin, and can clearly mean other things than the literal carrying.

Answer (score 5):

*Graviter* can indeed have several meanings, but it cannot modify *rem*, for the simple reason that it isn't even an adjective -- it is an adverb. And since *gravis* essentially means "heavy," *graviter* means "heavily, deeply, severely," etc. (For more details, see [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgravis).)

*Graviter ferre* therefore means, roughly, "to bear heavily," and usually that is understood as in bearing one's fate, not carrying a physical object. (If you think *graviter* has many meanings, just look up *ferre* in a dictionary of your choice.) However, English "bear" tends to emphasize resilience, whereas my impression from the Latin examples is that they tend to emphasize being affected, like "to be weighed down."

For example (from a letter by Servius Sulpicius to Cicero):

> Postea quam mihi renuntiatum est de obitu Tulliae, filiae tuae, sane quam pro eo ac debui graviter molesteque tuli ...
> *When I learnt about the death of your daughter Tullia, I was, as I must, affected most heavily and grievously ...*

[If you are somewhat new to Latin, this is probably a difficult sentence. It becomes clearer when you know that (a) *sane quam* is a fixed expression meaning "exceedingly" etc. (source of my "most"), and (b) *pro eo atque* is another fixed expression meaning essentially "like" (*pro eo atque debui* = like I had to).]

Depending on context, it can also take on a more negative meaning, e.g. *graviter et acerbe ferre* could be translated as "to resent bitterly" etc.

Not knowing what *rem* your *puer* is bearing, we can make no further guesses. It might even be a heavy thing ;-)